# What is a synonym for "necessary kindness"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm currently searching for a word for what I call "necessary kindness".

Let's say there are two people who normally don't get along with each other. When they are together in public, however, they treat each other with politeness and respect, according to social norms.

By the way, the word doesn't necessarily have to have a negative connotation, nor does it need to convey rudeness or offensiveness.

**EDIT**

I would also like to be able to use a word in a situation such as when a friend or acquaintance compliments you.

> "You look nice today!" "I appreciate your ______ but that's not necessary"

In that case, the 2 people aren't "tolerating" each other just being unnecessarily polite.

Comment: Could it be *tolerance*?

Comment: Yes, I think tolerance is a fitting word but I would also like to be able to use a word in a situation such as when a friend or acquaintance compliments you. Per se, "You look nice today!" "I appreciate your ______ but that's not necessary" In that case, the 2 people aren't "tolerating" each other just being unnecessarily polite.

Comment: Sounds like **etiquette** to me. "The customary code of polite behaviour in society or among members of a particular profession or group:" http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/etiquette

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Keeping up appearances? Don

Answer (score 5):

Consider ***civility***, defined as

> courtesy; politeness ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/civility))

The people of your example can be said to be ***showing civility*** to one another, or ***being civil*** to one another.

The reason I think this word is a good fit in the situation you describe is because

> *Civility* comes from the Latin word *civilis*, meaning "relating to public life, befitting a citizen," ([Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/civility))

As such, the word connotes kind behavior and attitude *in public*, not necessarily in the privacy of one's own home or mind. The kindness is necessary *in public*, but not necessary elsewhere.

Comment: I was thinking *courtesy* myself.

Answer (score 1):

Perfunctory - adjective - performed merely as a routine duty; hasty and superficial:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/perfunctory

Comment: I feel that this word is satisfactory for the situation I've put forward.

Comment: Of course it’s ***perfunctoriness*** that fits in your sentence.

Comment: _Perfunctory_ implies insincerity or offhandedness. _Civil_ implies a good faith effort to get along. _Oversolicitous_ implies too much of an effort.